# Is my daughter British and can she get a British Passport

Tags: uk-citizenship

I am a British female, born in Wales 1960, now a US citizen 1999, my daughter was born in 1995 in the US.  Does she have to register as a British citizen to get a passport or can she just apply? I never registered her as a child but I believe she is British by descent through me.  I went to do gov website and they say she probably is but I am not sure where to go next to make sure or just try and apply for a British passport

Comment: Since she is over 18 she will be applying as an adult

Answer (score 5):

While there could be edge cases, you daughter is a UK citizen by descent. You can check here: https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen.

The edge cases would include your daughter not being your biological daughter (e.g., if you are transgender or a lesbian) or you being a UK citizen by descent (e.g., if you father was a diplomat working for a non-UK country).

Comment: note that this often doesn't apply to grandchildren.  if she wants to pass citizenship to her own children, i think she'll need to spend 3 years in the country

Comment: She is my biological daughter...so I guess we can just go ahead and apply for a passport and see if they accept or reject the application  - when I do that check on gov.uk they say she most probably is so I guess the passport route is the only way to establish her as a legal citizen....Thanks

Comment: She is almost 20, hopefully she can just apply as an adult and use my British birth certificate as proof of my nationality in the application..it looks like they want the original documents and will not take certified copies - hopefully the are good about returning them - these things are more valuable than gold!

Comment: @APeck children of British expats claiming citizenship is quite common. As for the documents, they are very good about the process. It might make a reasonable question to ask how (e.g., FedEx or US mail) to send the documents. I think, but am not sure, they will use a prepaid tracking envelope if you include one.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: One way to pass on British citizenship is having the child in Britain. And that child would be British citizen "other than by descent" which is the "better" way.